# Ошибка при Компиляции OpenCV с поддержкой Qt

Tags: opencv

Ошибка при компиляции OpenCV с поддержкой Qt. Перепробовал кучу постов, но всё без толку. Ошибка происходит всегда на этой стадии. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означает эта ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: в pro файле прописаны пути к include и lib файлам от OpenCV + что то вида `-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui` ?

Comment: Я ещё до этого не дошёл. Я пытаюсь скомпилировать библиотеку OpenCV под Qt. Пробовал много постов, в то числе и эти:
http://recog.ru/blog/opencv/4.html
http://pavelk.ru/kompilyaciya-opencv-2-4-6-v-windows-dlya-qt-5-1

Comment: А почему не взять готовый скомпилированный?

Comment: Подточенный под Qt? Если подкинешь ссылку, буду очень благодарен.) Я не смог найти.

Comment: я брал прямо с сайта - работало нормально. Код компилировался, картинки бегали.

Comment: Под Qt нужно бинарники по любому собирать. http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide

Comment: Бинарники подготовлены только под VS, ты не мог их просто взять и просто использовать в Qt. Это в документации написано, посмотри ссылку, что оставил.

Comment: А кто мешает использовать компилятор от VS? отлично работает.

Comment: А не пробовали делать так как в руководстве написано? Берете cmake-gui, ставите нужные флажки - и вперед. Я и под линукс, и под виндозу так собирал без проблем. Правда, я уже давно отказался собирать OpenCV с поддержкой Qt, ибо не вижу никаких плюсов